# 3 coins interpretation of the boy and girl paradox

Tags: probability, paradoxes

Mr. Smith has two children. At least one of them is a boy. What is the probability that both children are boys?

I think I have come up with a new interpretation for this problem. If children where coins, boys were heads and girls were tails, we would have $3$ coins: $2$ of them can be both heads and tails, and the other one is loaded so it can only be heads. We start throwing one of the $2$ normal coins. If it is heads, we throw the other normal coin. If it is tails, we throw the loaded coin. This way, the chance of both coins being heads ends up being ${1 \over 2}\cdot {1 \over 2}$, which is ${1 \over 4}$. This is neither ${1 \over 3}$ nor ${1 \over 2}$, which are the classic answers to this problem.

Is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: Why are you saying 3 coins, we have 2 children in the original problem and children are equivalent to coins

Comment: We have 3 coins, but we use only 2 of them. Just like there is an infinite amount of children in the world, but Mr. Smith only adopts 2 of them. We could also use 2 coins (one of them being loaded), but if the not loaded one came out heads, it wouldn't be necessary for the other one to be loaded. That's why i added another non-loaded coin, and supposed that we use one of the non-loaded coins first so we save the loaded one if it's not necessary..

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier with two coins, both fair.

Version (a): toss both coins.  If both are tails, start again.  Otherwise  record what happened.  About $\frac{1}{3}$ of records will show two heads.

Version (b): toss the first coin.  If it is tails, start again.  Otherwise toss the second coin and record what happened.  About $\frac{1}{2}$ of records will show two heads.

Your version is closer to *"There is a family who wants at least one son.  If their first child is a boy they will have another child, but if it is a girl then they intend to use adoption or gender-selective abortion to make sure their second is a boy."* That indeed would give a probability of $\frac14$ for the probability of two boys, but it is not either of the standard forms of the question.

Comment: Then, in both of your versions, what would Mr. Smith do with his first child if it was a girl? Kill her? That also isn't in the standard form of the question!

Comment: In version one, you know they have a son (e.g. they are parents at a boys-only school).  In version 2, you know a particular one of their children is a boy (e.g. you meet one of their children and it is a boy).

Comment: My version would be something like this: a psychic tells Mr Smith that at least one of his children will be a boy. Assuming the psychic is right, if the first child was a girl, the second one would be a guaranteed boy. If the first child was a boy, on the other hand, you would have a 1/2 chance of having another boy and a 1/2 chance of having a girl. 1/2 chance of having the second boy multiplied by the 1/2 chance of having the first boy equals the 1/4 chance of having two boys.

Comment: If you introduce psychics then you get into things like [Newcomb's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcomb%27s_paradox).  Here, given an prediction by the psychic, the probability that the first child is a boy may then not be $\frac12$

Comment: I have a similar situation which also envolves psychics. Mr. Smith's wife becomes pregnant, and, after having the child, Mr. Smith goes to a psychic, which tells Mr. Smith that he will have 2 children in his life, and that at least one of them will be a boy. In this situation, the psychic's prediction doesn't affect the gender of the first child (the prediction takes place after the birth of the first child). You may argue that the prediction would be the same even if the psychic made it before the first child's birth. I, however, think having the first child affects the psychic's prediction.

Answer (score -1):

In your method you are calculating based on the chance that if the first throw of normal coin is a head, however in the original problem one head is always guaranteed

Comment: Yeah, but in my method one head is always guaranteed too by having a tricked coin in case the first one doesn't come out heads.

Comment: `If in the first throw of one of the normal coin results in a tail we throw the loaded coin` but I don't see why you need to throw it, you already know the result (its always heads) and you are needed to finding the probability of occurrence of both heads in normal coins when one head is for sure, the third coin results doesn't affect the first two in any ways.

Comment: If the first coin came out tails, the only way to have at least one heads is to throw the loaded coin (or throw a fair coin until it comes out heads, which is essentially the same thing). If it comes out heads, however, you don't need to ensure it because you already have the heads.